# Update all objects in JPA entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I'm trying to update all my 4000 Objects in `ProfileEntity` but I am getting the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.QueryTimeoutException: The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.
```

this is my code:

```
public synchronized static void  setX4all() 
{

    em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM ProfileEntity p");
    List<ProfileEntity> usersList = query.getResultList();

    int a,b,x;
    for (ProfileEntity profileEntity : usersList) 
    {
        a = profileEntity.getA();
        b = profileEntity.getB();
        x = func(a,b);
        profileEntity.setX(x);

        em.getTransaction().begin();        
        em.persist(profileEntity);        
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    }

    em.close();

}
```

I'm guessing that I take too long to query all of the records from `ProfileEntity`.
How should I do it?

- I'm using Google App Engine so no UPDATE queries are possible.

**Edited 18/10**
In this 2 days I tried:
using Backends as Thanos Makris suggested but got to a dead end. You can see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921874/google-app-engine-backend-servlet-not-responding).
reading DataNucleus suggestion on Map-Reduce but really got lost.

I'm looking for a different direction. Since I only going to do this update once, Maybe I can update manually every 200 objects or so.
Is it possible to to query for the first 200 objects and after it the second 200 objects and so on?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Then, I would propose to use the Task Queue API to to this. There, by using cursors you will be able to query for a batch of entities, update them and store them back.

Answer (score 3):

Given your scenario, I would advice to run a native update query:

```
 Query query = em.createNativeQuery("update ProfileEntity pe set pe.X = 'x'");
 query.executeUpdate();
```

Please note: Here the query string is `SQL` i.e. `update **table_name**  set ....`

This will work better.

Comment: I abstracted my question too much. I edited my question, Is it will still work for this scenario?

Comment: is you function Java function? If yes, is there any in writing the same in DB? If you can move/copy the function in database, you can very well do that with query being -- `update ProfileEntity pe set pe.X = func(pe.a,pe.b)`.

Comment: Yes the function is in java. What do you mean move/copy the function in database? I tried to do as you written and now I get javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Bulk Update statements are not supported.

Comment: Oops the method name is `createSQLQuery` (I updated the answer). Please make sure, you are using `SQL` not `HQL`.  By moving/copying, I meant that if you could define the function in database as database function.

Comment: I think it is JPQL (I'm not sure, I don't really know the difference). But neither way EntityManager don't have createSQLQuery.

Comment: Ooops. its `createNativeQuery`. I remembered of the Hibernate session so mentioned `createSQLQuery`. Its SQL, I am talking not JPQL.

Answer (score 1):

Change the update process to use something like [Map-Reduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/). This means all is done in datastore. The only problem is that appengine-mapreduce is not fully released yet (though you can easily build the jar yourself and use it in your GAE app - many others have done so).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set(x) for all object's, better to user update statement (i.e. native SQL) using JPA entity manager instead of fetching all object's and update it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Your class behaves not very well -  JPA is not suitable for bulk updates this way - you just starting a lot of transaction in rapid sequence and produce a lot of load on the database. Better solution for your use case would be scalar query  setting all the objects without loading them into  JVM first ( depending on your objects structure and laziness you would load much more data as you think )

See hibernate reference:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct

Comment: I abstracted my question too much. I edited my question, Is it will still work for this scenario?

Comment: You just loading too much data into your EM - think about moving this update to backend completely, and maybe post complete stacktrace to see which query offended GAE

Comment: It seems that it barfed while lazy loading  all data ( what is line 3.5.3 )

Comment: System.out.println(usersList.size()); it is right after getResultList()

Comment: so it barfed while loading  all your data  - your problem is definitely in JPA mappings try to be as lazy as possible, especially with collections

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider the use of the [Task Queue API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview) that enable you to execute tasks up to 10min. If you want to update such a number of entities that Task Queues do not fit you, you could also consider the user of [Backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview).

Answer (score 0):

Put the transaction outside of the loop:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();        
for (ProfileEntity profileEntity : usersList) {
...
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
```