# Google App Engine backend servlet not responding

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend

I built a servlet that I'm trying to run in the backend. But after starting the the backend and sending post message to http://mybackend.myapp.appspot.com/update nothing is appening.
when I access: http://myapp.appspot.com/update the servlet is working but not in backend.
What am I doing wrong?

**Servlet code:**

```
public class UpdateServlet extends HttpServlet
{   
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("start long task");              
    }
}
```

**backends.xml**

```
<backends>
  <backend name="mybackend">
    <class>B1</class>
    <options>
      <dynamic>true</dynamic>
      <public>true</public>
    </options>
  </backend>
</backends>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>update</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>server.UpdateServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>update</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/update</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

The servlet at `http://mybackend.myapp.appspot.com/update` sends a HTTP 302 redirect `http://my-life.appspot.com`. So it's your code that's doing it.

Comment: It is not the real url it is just a pattern of what I have done. the real url is http://go.streetmeet2.appspot.com/geoupdate.

Comment: This Url produces a HTTP 500 error. You should check your logs for errors.

Comment: I already checked to log there is nothing in there as if the there request hadn't arrived maybe the url isn't correct. When I POST a request to streetmeet2.appspot.com/geoupdate it is working but in the frontend. When I'm trying do a backend job with POSTing a request to go.streetmeet2.appspot.com/geoupdate nothing appenes.