# Update query in DataStore of google app engine - java

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I am newbie to app engine. I want to update some fields of my entity in datastore. For that i have created `query` like below but neither it updates my entity nor throws error. I don't know where i am going wrong.I referred [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070007/how-to-update-a-field-value-of-a-data-store-in-google-app-engine-using-java) but i have huge collection of data. Therefor, for me, its very hard to fetch hundreds of records and persist them.Please help me to solve this problem.

Code:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "updateUserProfile", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, path = "userfeedmasterendpoint/updateProfile")
public void updateUserProfile(@Named("userName") String uName,
            @Named("uAbout") String userAbout) 
    {
       EntityManager mgr = null;
       try {
                mgr = getEntityManager();
                Query query = mgr
                        .createQuery("update UserFeedMaster u set u.userAbout = :uAbout where u.userName=:userName");
                query.setParameter("userName", uName);
                query.setParameter("uAbout", userAbout);
                query.executeUpdate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
       }
```

Comment: If you are saving like that, I would suggest you to try: https://github.com/mungo-appengine/mungo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query will only ask the datastore for a set of object satisfying a criteria and retrieve these. To update an object you need to retrieve it (with a query for instance), update this object and then put it back in the datastore (by calling your ORM put method).

Comment: ok...so you are trying to say that i can't execute `Update` query in Datastore ?

Comment: is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Yes, see this SO response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330120/update-query-using-jpa-and-google-app-engine.

Comment: Also, I think that JDO/JPA are not necessarily the right tool on AppEngine as like you experienced, some of their functionalities are not supported on this platform. Objectify feels much more natural when working with the datastore...

Comment: agreed, JDO/JPA keep you in the "relational world" by misleading you toward concepts that don't actually apply to the datastore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to AppEngine and you want to use the datastore in an easy way, you should look at Objectify. It is a java ORM for the Datastore. Here is a short description of the project :

*Objectify is a Java data access API specifically designed for the Google App Engine datastore. It occupies a "middle ground"; easier to use and more transparent than JDO or JPA, but significantly more convenient than the Low-Level API. Objectify is designed to make novices immediately productive yet also expose the full power of the GAE datastore.*

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/